# How to avoid making my co-worker feel dispatched or replaceble

Tags: teamwork

I'm trying to make a co-worker to add some kind of version control to her code in order to read her code, keep a backup of it and learn from it.

She has a lot of capacities in this company that are required but she lack of some "new" common practices developers do like version control as a short example.

I was told to try to get involved with her as much as I can in order to learn what she does to avoid going after her to get assistance in her "coding language" so I could start doing her job on my own so she can be working on more hardcore code that this enterprise needs.

Basically what she does with me is so simple that I could just learn quickly to do it instead of relying on her but I think she feels that she is "no longer" going to do whatever role she has with me right now but she will actually be required on more complex tasks where she's required and I'll learn this evil ancestral language only a 3 people know in this job.

SO how can I make her feel safe that she has nothing to worry about while sharing this information with me because she totally feels me as a threat instead of a coworker or part of the team

Comment: Evil ancestral language? You'll have to dive into some sort of escoteric language before you can call it "evil".

Comment: ABL is evil my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really your problem to solve?

Her manager should be selling the benefits to her, not you. If she doesn't agree with her manager, and prefers to continue as a silo, then it is no longer an issue of persuasion, but of 'Do this or else'. The reality could well be that she *is* no longer going to be performing that role; it's called Career Progression.